# Jetpack Compose CoroutineScope with Navigation

Tags: kotlin, scope, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, kotlin-coroutines

I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer. I have a ModalNavigationDrawer and 3 different Screens with TopAppBar. In the MainComposable() in which the Drawer is implemented I have instantiated the Drawerstate and a CoroutineScope like that:

```
@Composable
fun MainCompose() {

val navController = rememberNavController()
val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

**drawerstate** gets passed down to the Drawer and to Screen1, Screen2, and Screen3.
And **scope** gets passed to all different Screens. On default, when the App is opening I say that when the user clicks on the Hamburger Icon of the TopAppBar that NaVDrawer should open:

```
IconButton(onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.open() }})
```

Then the user chooses a destination from the drawer and clicks one of the Items from the NavDrawer. When clicking I say Drawer should close:

```
scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
```

Now my question is, why is there no conflict between the coroutines inside the CoroutineScope? If I navigate from default to screen2 then this happens:

coroutine1 from Screen1 gets canceled because the composable of DefaultScreen leaves the composition.

**coroutine2** from MainActivity is still running since clicking on the icon of the NavDrawerstill with value **Drawer.Closed**.
When the User now clicks on the HamburgerButton of the TopAppBar in Screen2 **coroutine3** starts with value **Drawer.Open**.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would there be a conflict between the coroutines? Are you expecting the code not to work? Why not?

Comment: No it works. Im wondering because if i have one coroutine running with the value: Drawer.Closed and another is running with Drawer.Open, how does the system knows that it should prefer one of these coroutines? if the drawer is open, what is the other coroutine doing?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Those coroutines run once, when you click the button. They don't continue running.

Answer (score 0):

@Jorn
Ok maybe i have forgot that drawerstate.close() is a function and that the coroutine job is inactive when the function has finished the task. i misunderstood the concept and thought that the coroutines holds all the time the value of DrawerState.